# Is it correct to say "Is this test of any use to me ?"

Tags: grammar

I am inquiring about a test called HAT. Since I have no information about the test, therefore, I am sending an email to the organization conducting this test. So, can I write "Is this test of any use to me?". I want to ask whether I can use the result of this test for scholarships and/or admission.

Comment: Why don't you type it in Word and see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this test **of any use** to me?

This will give a negative impression (using *any*). It implies that their test may not be useful in general (they don't know you, after all).

This one:

> Will this test **be useful** for me?

would be taken more positively, and specifically involves you.

Of course, you need to provide sufficient information about yourself for them to reach a conclusion.